# OnSuccess response is not coming using retrofit in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am new in Kotlin. I am trying to call the API with the help of retrofit and URL is send me the response but where I am doing mistake in `response.body()`? The value is not coming.

My JSON response:-

```
{
 "data": {
 "type": "accounts"
 "attributes": {
        "payment-type": "prepaid"
        }
  },
  "included": [
              {
               "type": "a"
               "attributes": {
                   "msn": "0468874507"
                  }
               },
               {
                "type": "b"
                "attributes": {
                     "msn": "38593"
                    }
               }
       ]
}
```

In DataApi.kt

```
interface DataApi {

    @GET("dbnjg")
    fun getDataList(): Call<ArrayList<DataValue>>
}
```

In DataValue.kt

```
class DataValue {

    @SerializedName("data")
    var data: Data? = null

    @SerializedName("included")
    val included: ArrayList<DataInclude>? = null
}
```

In ApiClient.kt

```
fun getApiClient(): Retrofit? {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
    }
    return retrofit
}
```

In MainActivity I am trying to get the response but I am not able to get the response. Where did I mis something or make a mistake?

MainActivity.kt

```
val apiInterface: DataApi = ApiClient().getApiClient()!!.create(DataApi::class.java)

    apiInterface.getDataList().enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<DataValue>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<DataValue>>?, response: Response<ArrayList<DataValue>>?) {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, ""+response?.body()!!, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            dataValue = response?.body()!!
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<DataValue>>?, t: Throwable?) {

        }

       })
```

Comment: well, are you getting any error then?

Comment: your json response is an JSONObject while in Call you are passing An array list.....just change to Call<DataValue> in DataApi Interface

Comment: @nik thank you its working

Comment: also you can generate responseClass by using this plugin for kotlin.......https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your interface DataApi Like this:

```
interface DataApi {
    @GET("dbnjg")
    fun getDataList(): Call<DataValue>
}
```

and call your api like this:

```
 apiInterface.getDataList().enqueue(object : Callback<DataValue> { 
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<DataValue>?, response:Response<DataValue>?) {
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, ""+response?.body()!!, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        dataValue = response?.body()!!
        val includedList=dataValue.included
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<DataValue>?, t: Throwable?) {

    }

   })
```